# Recursive division maze generation is returning error

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am building an application using JavaScript and am trying to generate a maze using the Recursive Division method. The maze is being generated in a n x m matrix, where m > n and n is the height and m is the width. In the matrix, walls take up a matrix[y][x] position (they are not thin barriers between spots in the matrix). I am using this as a guide: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/1/12/maze-generation-recursive-division-algorithm.

My code is as follows:

```
const HORIZONTAL = "HORIZONTAL";
const VERTICAL = "VERTICAL";

// this function gets called first
function GenerateRecursiveDivisionMaze(grid) {
  let height = grid.length;
  let width = grid[0].length;

  // all the positions of the walls in the matrix
  let wallNodes = [];

  divide(wallNodes, 0, 0, width, height, HORIZONTAL);

  return wallNodes;
}

function divide(wallNodes, row, col, width, height, direction) {
  if (width < 3 || height < 3) return;
  let horizontal = direction === HORIZONTAL;

  // start position of the wall, change col and row?
  let wallPositionX = x + (horizontal ? 0 : generateRandomNumber(0, width - 2));
  let wallPositionY =
    y + (horizontal ? generateRandomNumber(0, height - 2) : 0);

  // passage in the wall
  let passageX =
    wallPositionX + (horizontal ? generateRandomNumber(0, width) : 0);

  let passageY =
    wallPositionY + (horizontal ? 0 : generateRandomNumber(0, height));

  // direction of wall
  let directionX = horizontal ? 1 : 0;
  let directionY = horizontal ? 0 : 1;

  // how long will the wall be
  let length = horizontal ? width : height;

  // build the wall
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    wallPositionY += directionY;
    wallPositionX += directionX;
    let y = wallPositionY;
    let x = wallPositionX;

    // make everything a wall except the designated passage
    if (passageX !== x || passageY !== y) {
      let node = {
        row: y,
        col: x,
      };
      wallNodes.push(node);
    }
  }

  let nextHeight = horizontal ? wallPositionY - y + 1 : height;
  let nextWidth = horizontal ? width : wallPositionX - x + 1;
  let nextDirectionToSlice = getDirectionToSlice(nextWidth, nextHeight);
  let nextX = x;
  let nextY = y;

  // recurse for the left and top side of the wall:
  divide(wallNodes, nextX, nextY, nextWidth, nextHeight, nextDirectionToSlice);

  // recurse right or bottom
  let nextX2 = horizontal ? x : wallPositionX + 1;
  let nextY2 = horizontal ? wallPositionY + 1 : y;

  let nextHeight2 = horizontal ? y + height - wallPositionY - 1 : height;
  let nextWidth2 = horizontal ? width : x + width - wallPositionX - 1;
  let nextDirectionToSlice2 = getDirectionToSlice(nextWidth2, nextHeight2);

  // recurse for the right and bottom side of the wall:
  divide(
    wallNodes,
    nextX2,
    nextY2,
    nextWidth2,
    nextHeight2,
    nextDirectionToSlice2
  );
}

function getDirectionToSlice(width, height) {
  if (width > height) {
    return VERTICAL;
  } else if (height > width) {
    return HORIZONTAL;
  } else {
    return generateRandomNumber(0, 1) == 0 ? HORIZONTAL : VERTICAL;
  }
}

// Generate a random number between lowNum and highNum
function generateRandomNumber(lowNum, highNum) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (highNum - lowNum + 1)) + lowNum;
}
```

I have double checked my code multiple times and it seems right to me. However, whenever I run it I get an error saying: "Maximum call stack size exceeded". I dont know where the infinite recursion is happening.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

More on the topic of mazes: If I am trying to generate a maze that is appealing to the eyes, where the walls are spaced evenly and the maze looks [something like this](https://www.google.com/search?q=maze&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS901US901&sxsrf=ALeKk03uvnNZRNW3haJRmlJfDMHCD50U7A:1597552710447&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=6eCuf1SicSdjGM%252CyIUHATV12Ckj2M%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kR1Z7BVXe5LkbCpQzlF1h-QkkB19Q&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijqcPO857rAhXKJDQIHVxFAkkQ_h0wIXoECA4QCQ&biw=1280&bih=609#imgrc=6eCuf1SicSdjGM). Is recursive division the best way to do so? There is an aspect of randomness to where the walls are placed in the recursive division method and I am afraid the maze it outputs will not be appealing.

**Update:** Edited the divide function. The problem with maximum stack exceeded is now gone. However, the walls in the maze are grouping together so that there are times when there is more than one wall next to each other vertically, making a wall that is two nodes thick. I am now trying to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript recursions are used with [async and await](https://medium.com/jspoint/javascript-promises-and-async-await-as-fast-as-possible-d7c8c8ff0abc) functions so that we can wait until recursion finishes and returns result.

Please check fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/cvpwLrtn/

```js
const HORIZONTAL = "HORIZONTAL";
const VERTICAL = "VERTICAL";

GenerateRecursiveDivisionMaze([5000,5000]).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});

// this function gets called first
async function GenerateRecursiveDivisionMaze(grid) {
    let height = grid[0];
    let width = grid[1];

    // all the positions of the walls in the matrix
    let wallNodes = [];

    await divide(wallNodes, 0, 0, width, height, HORIZONTAL);

    return wallNodes;
}

async function divide(wallNodes, row, col, width, height, direction) {
    if (width <= 2 || height <= 2) return;

    let vertical = direction === VERTICAL;

    // start position of the wall
    let wallPositionCol = vertical ? generateRandomNumber(row + 2, width - 2) : row;
    let wallPositionRow = vertical ? col : generateRandomNumber(col + 2, height - 2);

    // passage in the wall
    let passageRow = vertical
        ? generateRandomNumber(col + 1, height - 1)
        : wallPositionRow;

    let passageCol = vertical
        ? wallPositionCol
        : generateRandomNumber(row + 1, width - 1);

    // direction of wall
    let directionCol = vertical ? 0 : 1;
    let directionRow = vertical ? 1 : 0;

    // how long will the wall be
    let length = vertical ? height : width;

    // build the wall
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        let row = wallPositionRow + directionRow * i;
        let col = wallPositionCol + directionCol * i;

        // make everything a wall except the designated passage
        if (passageRow !== row || passageCol !== col) {
            let node = {
                row: row,
                col: col,
            };
            wallNodes.push(node);
        }
    }

    let nextHeight = vertical ? height : wallPositionRow;
    let nextWidth = vertical ? wallPositionCol : width;
    let nextDirectionToSlice = getDirectionToSlice(nextWidth, nextHeight);
    let nextRow = row;
    let nextCol = col;

    // recurse for the left or top side of the wall:
    setTimeout( function () {
        divide(
            wallNodes,
            nextRow,
            nextCol,
            nextWidth,
            nextHeight,
            nextDirectionToSlice,
        );
    }, 1000);

    // recurse right or bottom
    let nextHeight2 = vertical ? height : Math.abs(height - wallPositionRow);
    let nextWidth2 = vertical ? Math.abs(width - wallPositionCol) : width;
    let nextDirectionToSlice2 = getDirectionToSlice(nextWidth2, nextHeight2);
    let nextCol2 = vertical ? wallPositionCol : col;
    let nextRow2 = vertical ? row : wallPositionRow;

    setTimeout(function () {
        divide(
            wallNodes,
            nextRow2,
            nextCol2,
            nextWidth2,
            nextHeight2,
            nextDirectionToSlice2,
        );
    }, 2000)

}

function getDirectionToSlice(width, height) {
    if (width > height) {
        return VERTICAL;
    } else if (height > width) {
        return HORIZONTAL;
    } else {
        return generateRandomNumber(0, 1) === 0 ? HORIZONTAL : VERTICAL;
    }
}

// Generate a random number between lowNum and highNum
function generateRandomNumber(lowNum, highNum) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (highNum - lowNum + 1)) + lowNum;
}
```

Edit:
Here I added `setTimeout` inside async divide function so that two recursions had time to clear stack, 1000 mean 1 sec you can decrese it or increase according to grid size, I tested this with grid size of `[200000,200000]`

Comment: Thank you for the response! I tried your implementation and am still receiving the same error :( In the fiddle, I changed the dimension in `GenerateRecursiveDivisionMaze([5,5])` to `GenerateRecursiveDivisionMaze([10, 20])` and going to console I see the same error I am getting in my project ("Max call stack exceeded").

Comment: @LeonLi Please check fiddle and answer I made changes so that you can run enormous grids also google more about recursions in js maybe you could optimize it even more, good luck!

Comment: Thanks again.However,  I changed the size in fiddle to `GenerateRecursiveDivisionMaze([10, 20])` but am still getting the same error

Comment: Forgot to mention that you should run this async function like this `GenerateRecursiveDivisionMaze([5000,5000]).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});` the **result** inside console.log is the output array you need you can make it like this: `GenerateRecursiveDivisionMaze(grid).then(result => {
    let output = result;
});` then do anything with **output**

Comment: So I think the method you provided only works on square matrices, not rectangular ones (which I need). If you try changing the dimension of `5000,5000` to something like `10,20`, an error is thrown

Comment: No just tried grid [100000,200000] worked as a charm, please tell me how you test it and where

Comment: Yea so I tried running it with those dimensions. Then I went to the console and it had this message in it `Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: sorry forgot to change jsfiddle only changed code snipped, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cvpwLrtn/) working one 
<br/>
Check this fiddle does it work there for you

Comment: Yeah it appears to work now in the fiddle. Just some follow up questions: Are the setTimeouts necessary? I might need to make a lot of calculations depending on the grid size and Im afraid it might slow everything down. Also, why is async required for recursion in JS? I would think it would work the same way as in languages such as Java.

Comment: About setTimeout yes they are necessary in this case If you do not care about milliseconds you can leave it as it is, about async [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#:~:text=Async%2Fawait%20makes%20your%20code,would%20with%20a%20synchronous%20operation.)is a good explanation. Well with Java they have only common root first half in the word :-) And in every programming language you can implement same algorithms very differently

Comment: Some of them good in memory allocation and some in recursions, some use browsers for interpreting and some use whole computer power to run programs, task defines which language to use

Comment: hmmmm I see. I am trying to use the code in my project and it is not working (nothing gets returned). I think this is because of the setTimeouts, which are delaying each stage of the recusion by 1-2 seconds. So in order to get all of the walls, it will take a long time. Since the function is async, I tried to put an `await` before recursively calling the `divide` functions instead of doing a setTimeout. But this produces the `Maximum Stack Exceeded` error again.

Comment: this few seconds pass while your page is loading so it is not noticeable, decrease timeout to 100 in the first divide and remove setTimeout in second and make await divide(), so the purpose of it to run both divide async with little delay from one another

Comment: you can decrease it even to 5 ms

Comment: Nothing is being returned even when it is 5ms :(. Ill do some more digging. Along with the async problem, I think another problem may lie in the algorithm itself and how I am bisecting the grid in general. I am printing the wall positions to console and am getting a lot of duplicate numbers.

Comment: try to use [paper.js](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/) or [chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) for visualization it is much easier to understand where your calculations deviate, also about timeout you should set it that way so first recursion finish before second so play with ms, further digging is up to you, this thread already became too big)